# how to get the return value of an async function after then is called on the async function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Promises seem really straight forward. But every time I come across it, I have to do workarounds, when in fact I only want a function to be executed synchronously.

I'm wondering if I somehow missed how to do it properly because it seems so obvious how it should work.

Imagine the following code

```
getData()
.then(data => {
  const dates = [];
  generateDates(30, new Date(), dates)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
})
```

The promise of generateDates() is resolved before the dates array is finished populating, thus the console.log() returns undefined.

Why is then() on generateDates() called before the function returns? The function should only return once the dates array is completely populated. Promises don't make sense to me this way.

```
const generateDates = async(n, date, dates) => {
  if (n === 0) {
    return dates;
  }
  dates.push(date);
  n--;
  date = date - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  generateDates(n, date, dates);
}
```

Comment: I don't see that generatedate is an asynchronous function.

Comment: `const generateDates(n, date, dates) {` is a syntax error and doesn't even return a promise (nor should it), so I don't see how `generateDates(…).then(…)` could work at all.

Comment: "*how to get the return value of an async function after then is called*" - you get it *inside* the `then` callback, not after the call. "*In fact I only want a function to be executed synchronously*" - you're asking for the impossible there if that function does something asynchronous. Embrace asynchrony, always return a promise from such functions, and it will become straightforward. Especially with `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: @lissettdm sorry, fatal typo. the whole signature was messed up

Comment: cause generateDates is a recursive function, you have to return the recursive call. returning it will make the result be the array value instead of undefined.

Comment: @urchmaney you're a hero. totally offtopic answer+ solution because I forgot the return statement. I had the same issue somewhere else in the past. thought it's the same again. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that generateDates is been resolved before the dates finish populating, it because the recursive call is not been returned.

```js
 const getData = async() => {};

 const generateDates = async(n, date, dates) => {
      if (n === 0) {
        return dates;
      }
      dates.push(date);
      n--;
      date = date - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
      return generateDates(n, date, dates);
    }

    const dates = [];
    getData().then(data => {
      const dates = [];
       generateDates(2, new Date(), dates).then(result =>        console.log(result))

    })
```

Comment: it happens. glad to help out.